# regex - dash symbol match

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match the "-" symbol

https://regex101.com/r/7NuWBy/1

```
([0-9]+) (Cat) · ([0-9]+) (Dog) · ([0-9]+) (Fish)
```

This is the text

```
134 Cat · 13 Dog · — Fish
14 Cat · 133 Dog · 1 Fish
124 Cat · 1333 Dog · 32 Fish
```

Comment: Just place `—` inside the character class: `([0-9—]+) (Cat) · ([0-9—]+) (Dog) · ([0-9—]+) (Fish)`

Comment: @anubhava - that did it.

Comment: @anubhava if you put this as an solution I can accept your answer to give you credit if you like.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use a `.` directly instead use `\.`
because a `.` means any character except a newline `\n`
so the correct regex would be:

```
([0-9]+|-) (Cat) \· ([0-9]+|-) (Dog) \· ([0-9]+|-) (Fish)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't match it.

Answer (score 0):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

Your desired regex must include hyphen also since you want to match substrings that include hyphens as well. Your intended regex would be:

```
([0-9—]+) (Cat) \· ([0-9—]+) (Dog) \· ([0-9—]+) (Fish)
```

A dot has a special meaning and it must also be escaped to avoid matching just any character.

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7NuWBy/3)